# Cmake can't found Boost

Tags: boost, cmake

I try to build my project with cmake. Evrything but boost work. For boost i get this message.

```
Boost version: 1.56.0    
  Boost include path: C:/Boost/include/boost-1_56    
  Could not find the following Boost libraries:    
          boost_program_options

No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of Boost.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:27 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

Can someone tell me what I did wrong? I fixed the environment variable for boost as follows : `C:\Boost`.

Comment: _"I fixed the environment variable for boost…"_
Which one? Take a look into `FindBoost.cmake` module -- it has detailed description how exactly it works and trying to find boost in your system.

Comment: It looks like you either did not compile program_options for the current configuration, or placed the binaries to a directory that the find script cannot find from the specified `BOOST_ROOT`.